# Link works in "preview", but not when posted

Tags: support, bug, firefox, markdown-preview, browsers

Everything works correctly in Chrome, but in Firefox, I'm seeing the following problem:

Both [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/595332/44672) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/34645/44672) answers link to

```
http://www.tau.ac.il/~kantor/QUIZ/96/A01.96.html
```

But the link works correctly only in the second answer. It also works in the first answer from the preview (while editing), but not when posted.

When it "doesn't work", it just shows some kind of incomplete landing page of the Tel Aviv University. I think this might have something to do with a redirect to `https`.

Here's the [link](http://www.tau.ac.il/%7Ekantor/QUIZ/96/A01.96.html), again. Opens fine in the "preview"...

Comment: ... doesn't open when posted.

Comment: Works in chrome indeed.

Comment: The first link encodes that `~` as `%7E`, the second one doesn’t. It seems Firefox shows the decoded URL in the URI bar, i.e. `https://www.tau.ac.il/~kantor/QUIZ/96/A01.96.html`, in both cases, but actually redirects to different URLs. They’re resolved differently: `GET https://www.tau.ac.il/~kantor/QUIZ/96/A01.96.html` results in `200` and the intended article, whereas `GET https://www.tau.ac.il/%7Ekantor/QUIZ/96/A01.96.html` results in a `404` with this Hebrew page. I don’t know how Stack Exchange encodes the URLs when parsing Markdown and creating HTML; this is possibly CommonMark related.

Comment: Confirmed, the recent post escapes the URL, breaking it; while in the post from 2012, it is unmangled from what appears in both the original text and the preview.